# Unable to submit values from CSV to php

Tags: php, html, csv

This is my first attempt at PHP and therefore have minuscule knowledge of php.
I am trying to make a form that would get values from a csv --> allow to select multiple values --> post to a php file.
**I can get the table to display and select multiple values but upon submit nothing happens**.
Here is the code snippet. Appreciate any help with the fix

```
<form action="Test.php" method="POST">
<label for="Cluster"><br><br><b>Choose Clusters:</b><br></label>
<br>
<select name="Cha_Cluster[]" id="cha_Cluster" size ="15" multiple>
<?php
    $fileHandle = fopen("cha_cluster.csv", "r");
    while (($row = fgetcsv($fileHandle, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $cha_cluster = $row[0];
?>
    <option value="<?php echo $cha_cluster;?>"><?php echo $cha_cluster;?></option>
<?php
    }
?>
</select>   
<br><br>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
                </form>
<?php
if (isset($_POST["cha_cluster"]))
{
    print_r ($_POST["cha_cluster"]);
}   
?>
```

Comment: Your select field is named `Cha_Cluster`, but you are checking for the existence of item in $_POST with the key `cha_cluster` - see the difference?

Comment: @CBroe Thanks!! Can't believe I didn't see that in the last few hours trying to find whats wrong.